# Vue router link button component

Tags: vue.js, button, components

I'm building simple button component with Vue. I'm trying to store a prop "link" in the component.

Then in the parent component I just want to use the button component, like:

```
<btn :link="page link" />
```

I can do this with simple 'a' tag, but i want to push with router to trigger my page transitions. Maybe I'm doing something really wrong with composing the component. If someone have some different idea, I'm up to.

I need a button component where in the parent component I pass the link as data.

```js
<script>
export default {
 props: {
  link: {
   type: String,
   required: false,
  },
 },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
 <div class="btn" @click="$router.push(link)">
  <slot>btn text</slot>
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Page transitions should work when using a `router-link`.

Comment: Yes its working, I just dont know how to pass the link data from parent component

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but i was passing the link data in parent with ':' and it should be without it since im not binding nothing.
So the working code now looks like this

```js
<script>
export default {
 props: {
  link: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
  },
 },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
 <div class="btn" @click="$router.push(link)">
  <slot>btn text</slot>
 </div>
</template>
```

and in the parent component i just call it like this

```
<btn link="contact" />  // go to contact page
```

Comment: you use `:` in order to bind prop or attribute to a defined property in your script like explained in my edited answer